# How can I prevent TypeScript from seeing Node.js types in my browser-targeting scripts?

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a Chrome extension using TypeScript and have hit a snag. Everything was working fine initially, but when adding a new dependency (webpack), the type definitions it brings in cause my working scripts to now produce compilation errors where the Node types conflict with Chrome types.

The problem can be seen by following these steps:

1. `mkdir type-conflict && cd type-conflict`
2. `npm init`
3. `npm install -D @types/chrome typescript`
4. `npx tsc --init`
5. `echo 'const timeout: number = setTimeout(() => console.log(timeout), 0);' > example.ts`
6. `npx tsc` — this works just fine and produces example.js
7. `npm install -D @types/webpack webpack` — this brings in the Node types transitively
8. `npx tsc` — this time, you get the error "example.ts(1,7): error TS2322: Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'."

The only script I want to see the Node types is the webpack configuration script itself, which [has its own `tsconfig-for-webpack-config.json`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript); how can I get TypeScript to ignore those types in the main `tsconfig.json` so that my scripts can use the browser types again?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the `"types"` you do want it to pick up in `tsconfig.json`? Otherwise they're all pulled in per [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types).

Comment: @jonrsharpe — Yep, that did the trick; I wasn't aware of that option. If you post that as an answer, I'll happily mark it as accepted.

Comment: You can also use `NodeJS.Timeout` type.